# How to get the specific data through api by using flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I am beginner in flutter and working on fetching the specific data by using flutter_bloc package. I have successfully fetch the api data by using flutter_bloc in HomePage but how do i fetch the more specific data.For example in Home Page it fetch the data when i open the app and there is a button at the bottom which moves to new screen that is a Settings Screen which has Two radio buttons and one Raised Button named as Save.When i select any of the radiobutton and click on save button it should moves back to the homepage and calls the api and update the data which was already fetched in homepage. Below is the dart code and bloc code, it will be lengthy but hope you understand my code

> Main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<PrayerBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => PrayerBloc(repository: PrayerRepositoryImpl()),
        ),
        BlocProvider<MethodBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => MethodBloc(methodRepository: MethodRepositoryImpl()),
        ),
      ],
      child: HomePage(),
    );
```

> HomePage.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  PrayerBloc prayerBloc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    prayerBloc = BlocProvider.of<PrayerBloc>(context);
    prayerBloc.add(FetchPrayerEvent());
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return Material(
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Prayer API"),
              ),
              body: Container(
                child: BlocListener<PrayerBloc, PrayerState>(
                  listener: (context, state) {
                    if (state is PrayerErrorState) {
                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text(state.message),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: BlocBuilder<PrayerBloc, PrayerState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is InitialPrayerState) {
                        return buildLoading();
                      } else if (state is PrayerLoadingState) {
                        return buildLoading();
                      } else if (state is PrayerLoadedState) {
                        return buildArticleList(state.item);
                      } else if (state is PrayerErrorState) {
                        return buildErrorUi(state.message);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget buildLoading() {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
  Widget buildErrorUi(String message) {
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(
          message,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget buildArticleList(List<Item> item) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: item == null ? 0 : item.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int pos) {
        return new Container(
          child: new Center(
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: new Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text("Fajr"),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                              ),
                              Text(item[pos].fajr),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text("Dhuhr"),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                              ),
                              Text(item[pos].dhuhr),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Builder(
                            builder: (context)=>
                                RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsPage()),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

> Prayer_bloc.dart

```
class PrayerBloc extends Bloc<PrayerEvent, PrayerState> {
  PrayerRepository repository;
  PrayerBloc({@required this.repository});
  @override
  PrayerState get initialState => InitialPrayerState();
  @override
  Stream<PrayerState> mapEventToState(
    PrayerEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is FetchPrayerEvent) {
      yield PrayerLoadingState();
      try {
        List<Item> item = await repository.getItem();
        yield PrayerLoadedState(item: item);
      } catch (e) {
        yield PrayerErrorState(message: e.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> PrayerEvent.dart

```
abstract class PrayerEvent extends Equatable {}
class FetchPrayerEvent extends PrayerEvent {
  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object> get props => null;
}
```

> PrayerState.dart

```
abstract class PrayerState extends Equatable {
  const PrayerState();
}
class InitialPrayerState extends PrayerState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
class PrayerLoadingState extends PrayerState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
class PrayerLoadedState extends PrayerState {
  List<Item> item;
  PrayerLoadedState({@required this.item});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => null;
}
class PrayerErrorState extends PrayerState {
  String message;
  PrayerErrorState({@required this.message});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}
```

> PrayerRepository.dart

```
abstract class PrayerRepository {
  Future<List<Item>> getItem();
}
class PrayerRepositoryImpl implements PrayerRepository {
  @override
  Future<List<Item>> getItem() async {
    var response = await http.get("https://muslimsalat.com/riyadh.json?key=");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      List<Item> item = Welcome.fromJson(data).items;
      return item;
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

So these dart code fetch the data from api and load in HomePage when i open the application.Now the second page which is settings page, below is the code

> SettingsPage.dart

```
class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsPageState createState() => _SettingsPageState();
}
class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  int selectedRadio;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedRadio=0;
  }
  setSelectedRadio(int val){
    setState(() {
      selectedRadio=val;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            BlocBuilder<MethodBloc,MethodState>(
              builder: (context,state){
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Prayer Methods",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        RadioListTile(
                            value: 1,
                            groupValue: selectedRadio,
                            activeColor: Colors.black,
                            title: Text(
                              "Egyptian General Authority of Survey",
                            ),
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              print(val);
                              setSelectedRadio(val);
                            }),
                        RadioListTile(
                            value: 2,
                            groupValue: selectedRadio,
                            activeColor: Colors.black,
                            title: Text(
                              "University Of Islamic Sciences, Karachi (Shafi)",
                            ),
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              print(val);
                              setSelectedRadio(val);
                            }),
                        FloatingActionButton(
                            onPressed: (){
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                              BlocProvider.of<MethodBloc>(context).add(MethodChangedEvent(method: selectedRadio));  //I have try this code in onpressed but unfortunately not succeed
                              print(selectedRadio);
                            },
                            child: Text('Save')
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  }
```

> MethodBloc.dart

```
class MethodBloc extends Bloc<MethodEvent, MethodState> {
  MethodRepository methodRepository;
  MethodBloc({@required this.methodRepository});
  @override
  MethodState get initialState => InitialMethodState();
  @override
  Stream<MethodState> mapEventToState(
    MethodEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if(event is MethodChangedEvent){
    yield MethodLoadingState();
    try {
    List<Item> item = await methodRepository.getMethod(event.method);
    yield MethodLoadedState(item: item);
    } catch (e) {
    yield MethodErrorState(message: e.toString());
    }
    }
  }
}
```

> MethodEvent.dart

```
abstract class MethodEvent extends Equatable {
  const MethodEvent();
}
class MethodChangedEvent extends MethodEvent {
  final int method;
  MethodChangedEvent({this.method}) : assert(method != null);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => null;
}
```

> MethodState.dart

```
abstract class MethodState extends Equatable {
  const MethodState();
}
class InitialMethodState extends MethodState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
class MethodLoadingState extends MethodState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
class MethodLoadedState extends MethodState {
  List<Item> item;
  MethodLoadedState({@required this.item});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => null;
}
class MethodErrorState extends MethodState {
  String message;
  MethodErrorState({@required this.message});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}
```

> MethodRepository.dart

```
abstract class MethodRepository{
  Future<List<Item>> getMethod(int method);
}
class MethodRepositoryImpl implements MethodRepository {
  @override
  Future<List<Item>> getMethod(int method) async {
    var response = await http.get("https://muslimsalat.com/riyadh/$method.json?key=");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      List<Item> item = Welcome.fromJson(data).items;
      return item;
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

> PrayerModel.dart

```
class Welcome {
  String title;
  String query;
  String welcomeFor;
  int method;
  String prayerMethodName;
  String daylight;
  String timezone;
  String mapImage;
  String sealevel;
  TodayWeather todayWeather;
  String link;
  String qiblaDirection;
  String latitude;
  String longitude;
  String address;
  String city;
  String state;
  String postalCode;
  String country;
  String countryCode;
  List<Item> items;
  int statusValid;
  int statusCode;
  String statusDescription;
  Welcome({
    this.title,
    this.query,
    this.welcomeFor,
    this.method,
    this.prayerMethodName,
    this.daylight,
    this.timezone,
    this.mapImage,
    this.sealevel,
    this.todayWeather,
    this.link,
    this.qiblaDirection,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.address,
    this.city,
    this.state,
    this.postalCode,
    this.country,
    this.countryCode,
    this.items,
    this.statusValid,
    this.statusCode,
    this.statusDescription,
  });
  factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
    title: json["title"],
    query: json["query"],
    welcomeFor: json["for"],
    method: json["method"],
    prayerMethodName: json["prayer_method_name"],
    daylight: json["daylight"],
    timezone: json["timezone"],
    mapImage: json["map_image"],
    sealevel: json["sealevel"],
    todayWeather: TodayWeather.fromJson(json["today_weather"]),
    link: json["link"],
    qiblaDirection: json["qibla_direction"],
    latitude: json["latitude"],
    longitude: json["longitude"],
    address: json["address"],
    city: json["city"],
    state: json["state"],
    postalCode: json["postal_code"],
    country: json["country"],
    countryCode: json["country_code"],
    items: List<Item>.from(json["items"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x))),
    statusValid: json["status_valid"],
    statusCode: json["status_code"],
    statusDescription: json["status_description"],
  );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "title": title,
    "query": query,
    "for": welcomeFor,
    "method": method,
    "prayer_method_name": prayerMethodName,
    "daylight": daylight,
    "timezone": timezone,
    "map_image": mapImage,
    "sealevel": sealevel,
    "today_weather": todayWeather.toJson(),
    "link": link,
    "qibla_direction": qiblaDirection,
    "latitude": latitude,
    "longitude": longitude,
    "address": address,
    "city": city,
    "state": state,
    "postal_code": postalCode,
    "country": country,
    "country_code": countryCode,
    "items": List<dynamic>.from(items.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "status_valid": statusValid,
    "status_code": statusCode,
    "status_description": statusDescription,
  };
}
class Item {
  String dateFor;
  String fajr;
  String shurooq;
  String dhuhr;
  String asr;
  String maghrib;
  String isha;
  Item({
    this.dateFor,
    this.fajr,
    this.shurooq,
    this.dhuhr,
    this.asr,
    this.maghrib,
    this.isha,
  });
  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
    dateFor: json["date_for"],
    fajr: json["fajr"],
    shurooq: json["shurooq"],
    dhuhr: json["dhuhr"],
    asr: json["asr"],
    maghrib: json["maghrib"],
    isha: json["isha"],
  );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "date_for": dateFor,
    "fajr": fajr,
    "shurooq": shurooq,
    "dhuhr": dhuhr,
    "asr": asr,
    "maghrib": maghrib,
    "isha": isha,
  };
}
class TodayWeather {
  int pressure;
  String temperature;
  TodayWeather({
    this.pressure,
    this.temperature,
  });
  factory TodayWeather.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TodayWeather(
    pressure: json["pressure"],
    temperature: json["temperature"],
  );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "pressure": pressure,
    "temperature": temperature,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've defined the Model for the Stream in bloc, you can easily access the object using BlocBuilder. As demonstrated on the code you've shared, you're able to build a List with `buildArticleList()` from the Stream. To access a specific data, you can follow a similar approach for that object.

Comment: Is it `bloclistener` works? And `buildArticleList()` i already called this method in blocbuilder.